# Java: Detect non-displayable chars for a given Character Encoding

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, validation

I'm currently working on an application to validate and parse CSV-files.
The CSV files have to be encoded in UTF-8, although sometimes we get files in a false encoding.
The CSV-files most likely contain special characters of the German alphabet (Ä, Ö, Ü, ß) as most of the texts within the CSV file are in German language.

For the part of the validator, i need to make sure, the file is UTF-8 encoded. As long as there are no special characters present, there is most likely no problem with parsing.

What i have tried so far is to read the file as bytes and use some libraries to detect (or guess) the encoding. I tried most of possibilities of this blog post: http://fredeaker.blogspot.com/2007/01/character-encoding-detection.html

But all libraries I tried didn't return the correct encoding and therefore I couldn't parse the special characters.

Now to my question:
Is there a way to determine for a given Character Encoding like UTF-8 to detect characters that are not encoded correctly? So basically the characters that are displayed in the (Eclipse) console as quesion marks.

Or is there any other way to correctly determine the character encoding?
I just need to know if it's UTF-8 or not.

Thank you all in advance for your help! :)

Best Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Byte sequences that cannot be decoded correctly will be replaced with the "replacement character", `\uFFFD`, which is displayed like this: �. However, if the output device doesn't support that character, it is likely to use a question mark (?) instead.

So, after decoding the UTF-8 data into `String` objects, search for occurrences of `\uFFFD`.

Alternatively, if you set up an `InputStreamReader` with an instance of [`CharsetDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) that you create yourself, you can get a lot more control. For example, you can specify that if any byte sequences that cannot be decoded, an `Exception` should be raised. Or you can ignore them. Or you can specify a different character as the replacement character.

Comment: I get key strokes as `char` from a key event and every non displayable character was `\uFFFF`

Comment: @Qbyte Key events don’t use a character encoding. This question (and answer) don’t apply to keyboard input in a GUI, but only once you need to convert characters to bytes for transmission or storage.

Comment: @erickson The title of this question matches the best with what I searched for. I just wanted to add this comment so others can also try to use `\uFFFF`.

Comment: @Qbyte If you are seeing `'\uFFFF'`, it's because of some bug unique to your code. You could ask a new question with an [mcve] to find out how where these invalid characters are coming from. `\uFFFF` is not a valid character; if you were reading from a file or stream, I'd guess that you are casting EOF (-1) to a `char`, but since you're not, I'd be curious to see what's happening.

Comment: @erickson To be more specific: I get these characters from the `key` property of the `PApplet` from the "Processing" library. This `key` is `\uFFFF` if I type some non displayable character like shift, left arrow and so on. So it might be just Processing.

Comment: @Qbyte I looked at the docs, [`getKeyChar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()) specifies that `CHAR_UNDEFINED` (`'\uFFFF'`) is returned if a key event has no character associated with it. I'd expect this for keys like "Page Up", "Esc", etc. that don't print anything.

Comment: @erickson Thank you! Nice to know why it is exactly this character

Answer (score 2):

If the text is German and the encoding isn't UTF-8, it's probably windows-1252.  Or something compatible with windows-1252, like ISO-8859-15.  That being the case, Laforge's [GuessEncoding](http://glaforge.free.fr/wiki/index.php?wiki=GuessEncoding) should be all you need.  I've used it quite a bit and never had a problem, and that's working almost exclusively with English text; German should be even easier to detect.

I see he still hasn't specified a license on his blog or in the source files, but I know those classes are used in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I'll try them tomorrow :)