# To write degree symbol in .csv file

Tags: javascript, android, csv, utf

I am trying to write °C and °F symbol into my csv file from android code, but it is displaying some junk in the csv file.Thank you in advance. Please help me in writing degree symbol into csv file

```
 PrintWriter csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
 csvWriter.print("°C");
 csvWriter.close();
```

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3618952/927408

Answer (score 3):

There is a Unicode symbol for Celsius degrees that you can use in Java: **"\u2103"** and also, for Fahrenheit you can use: **"\u2109"**.

Comment: what is the encoding for the output file?

Comment: @mihail Its default.I am not setting anything.