# How to create a unit test to detect if someone edited the file using the wrong encoding?

Tags: java, file, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using Java, Spring and I would like to prevent some invalid chars on the message property files.

Some colleges use different operational systems, IDEs and setups. As our language is portuguese and the Windows default encoding is Windows-1252 (or CP-1252), it's common to have some confusion about special (accented) chars, like á, ã, õ, etc when editing files, because some of them could use a different encoding and mess up the messages property file, like this:

```
1002 = O pedido não foi encontrado
1003 = O pedido j� est� finalizado
1004 = A situa��o do hist�rico do pedido n�o � permitida
```

The above file is originally a UTF-8 file but someone edit the file with Windows-1252 encoding, adding two new entries (1003 and 1004) and creating this weird question marks on the place of the accents when reading the file as a UTF-8 file.

So, I'm thinking on a unit test to detect this problem on the file. How could I do this unit test? Thanks!

Comment: You could read the file bytewise and check if there are any "unusual" bytes and count them. If there are than normally should appear than the test fails.

Comment: @mayamar, thank you. you gave me some insight to found the answer. I will put my answer here, but you can add yours because I will upvote :)

Comment: Thanks. In my special case I had the problem with german Umlauten (ä, ö, ü). I knew what encodings where possible and checked the specific values of the Umlaute in each encoding and counted them. That way I could say the encoding is okay or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of @Mayamar and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3619096/2387977).

```
@Test
public void verifyInvalidCharsOnMessages() throws IOException {
    verifyInvalidChars("src/main/resources/i18n/messages.properties");
    verifyInvalidChars("src/main/resources/i18n/messages_pt_BR.properties");
}

private void verifyInvalidChars(String file) throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
    p.load(new InputStreamReader(input, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    Enumeration<String> enums = (Enumeration<String>) p.propertyNames();
    while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = enums.nextElement();
        String value = p.getProperty(key);
        if (value.indexOf('\uFFFD') > 0) {
            fail();
        }
    }

}
```